# Print out matrix in R within function for which each column has a specified number of digits defined by a function parameter

Tags: r, function, return, digits

I have been thinking about this for some time already but I cannot find the solution. Here is the problem.
I have a function that iteratively calculated the root for a function that I plug in there. So for every iteration I come closer to the final solution (Newton procedure). Within the function I build a matrix that stores the number of the iteration (i), the value for x (x) and the value for f(x) (y).

```
matrix <- rbind(matrix, c(i,x,y))
```

The function itself works perfectly fine. But I want to print out the result in a specific way.
I want to return the matrix that is built in the function like this:

```
       [,1]      [,2]          [,3]             
  [1,] "1"   "0.000"       "3.000"              
  [2,] "2"   "-299999.975" "89999985109.735"
  [3,] "3"   "-150000.381" "22500114442.253"
  [4,] "4"   "-75000.123"  "5625014307.234"     
  [5,] "5"   "-37500.048"  "1406253577.781" 
  [6,] "6"   "-18750.030"  "351563619.088"  
  [7,] "7"   "-9375.093"   "87890906.234"       
  [8,] "8"   "-4687.507"   "21972727.599"   
  [9,] "9"   "-2343.753"   "5493182.588"
```

What I am doing at the moment is:

```
return(matrix(sprintf(c("%.0f","%.3f","%.3f"),matrix),nrow=N))
```

But this yields

```
    [,1]      [,2]          [,3]             
  [1,] "1"       "0"           "3"              
  [2,] "2.000"   "-299999.975" "89999985109.735"
  [3,] "3.000"   "-150000.381" "22500114442.253"
  [4,] "4"       "-75000"      "5625014307"     
  [5,] "5.000"   "-37500.048"  "1406253577.781" 
  [6,] "6.000"   "-18750.030"  "351563619.088"  
  [7,] "7"       "-9375"       "87890906"       
  [8,] "8.000"   "-4687.507"   "21972727.599"   
  [9,] "9.000"   "-2343.753"   "5493182.588"
```

So the digits are somehow specified by column and not by row.
In a next step - to make it even more complicated - my function is supposed to have a parameter that allows users to specify the number of digits of column 2 and 3.
so something like:

```
newton <- function(fx, p=0)
```

Where p is the number of digits and by default 0.

Can somebody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want strings? otherwise I would use `as.integer` for the first col and than `print` with parameter `digits`...

Comment: BTW, sprintf converts the matrix to a vector then applies the formats to the values (recycling the formats if they're less than the values). When you convert a matrix to a vector, R starts from the values in the 1st column then pass to the 2nd and so on. That's the reason why it seems that sprintf applies the formats to the rows...

Comment: Thanks for the input. The problem is that the digits only need to be specified for column 2 and three. column 1 needs to be printed with 0 decimal digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your matrix has always 3 columns you can simply do:

```
x.digits = 3
y.digits = 4

mxStr <- 
cbind(sprintf('%d',mx[,1]),
      sprintf(paste('%.',x.digits,'f',sep=''),mx[,2]),
      sprintf(paste('%.',y.digits,'f',sep=''),mx[,3])
      )
```

Of course you can wrap this code in a function and pass `x.digits` and `y.digits` as parameters...

Comment: This is basically it... Sadly I made a mistake as I need the numbers as.numeric. But when I add this the whole design of the matrix gets destroyed...

Comment: Figured it out... I just do: `mxStr <- as.numeric(cbind(sprintf('%d',matrix[,1]),
                sprintf(paste('%.',x.digits,'f',sep=''),matrix[,2]),
                sprintf(paste('%.',y.digits,'f',sep=''),matrix[,3])))
        return(matrix(mxStr, i, 3))`

Comment: I don't get your problem... are you using this approach to round the values to a given number of digits ? Because if it's just for printing I don't understand why you need this matrix as numeric...

Comment: because I will need to visualize the results

Comment: Ok, so I suggest you to keep the original matrix and create a function that just prints it (with the code above), because in my opinion it's not correct to loose precision just to better print the results...